# Ionic DocumentViewer in UWP Windows not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

I'm trying to open and view a PDF using the [Ionic Native Document Viewer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer/). However, this thing isn't working. Here's my code.

```
this.pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);

this.pdf.getBuffer((buffer) => {
  var ut8 = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  var binaryArray = ut8.buffer;
  var blob = new Blob([binaryArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });

  this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'PDFIonic.pdf', blob, { replace: true }).then(fileEntry => {
    let url = fileEntry.toURL();
    this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
  });
});
```

I'm having this warning when the code reach the `this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});`

```
CSP14321: Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval' blob:' in Host Defined Policy: inline script, in ms-appx://connexus.tablet.v2/www/sitewaertsdocumentviewer/viewer.html at line 0 column 0. The resource will be blocked.
CSP14321: Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval' blob:' in Host Defined Policy: inline script, in ms-appx://connexus.tablet.v2/www/sitewaertsdocumentviewer/viewer.html at line 0 column 0. The resource will be blocked.
CSP14321: Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval' blob:' in Host Defined Policy: inline script, in ms-appx://connexus.tablet.v2/www/sitewaertsdocumentviewer/viewer.html at line 0 column 0. The resource will be blocked.
CSP14321: Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval' blob:' in Host Defined Policy: inline script, in ms-appx://connexus.tablet.v2/www/sitewaertsdocumentviewer/viewer.html at line 0 column 0. The resource will be blocked.
CSP14312: Resource violated directive ‘script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval' blob:’ in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked.
CSP14312: Resource violated directive ‘script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval' blob:’ in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked.
CSP14312: Resource violated directive ‘script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval' blob:’ in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked.
CSP14312: Resource violated directive ‘script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval' blob:’ in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked.
```

Any opinion/ideas will be a great help. Thanks!

This is my [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kM4cCQn8Bz4)